# CakePHP 3 - How to check if the date is valid?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I was reading the documentation and found it..

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html#comparing-with-intervals

But i can't apply this function "isWithinNext" or i'm not knowing HAH. I need to know if my date is valid, for example:

My Table's field is **"token_time_exp" = 2015-02-06 23:17:52** , this date expires in *72 hours or 3 days*.

What do i use? wasWithinLast? isWithinNext? or both are wrong.. Sorry, I started using the cake this week! :D

Saving token_time_exp:

```
$user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user,
                        [
                            'mail_temp' => $this->request->data['mail'],
                            'token_mail' => 12345,
                            'token_time_exp' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
                        ]);
```

Let's assume that today is day 9 and the token's day = 6, I suppose that would return true, because it's been 72 hours.. Right?

Now, I'll test if been 3 days..

```
if($users->token_time_exp->isWithinNext(3)){
            debug('Expired');//return true
        }else{
            debug('Valid');//return false
        }
```

Not show errors, it works, but I think I'm not knowing how to use: \

Comment: Hi, I like how you write the question :D ...  But we need to know how you declare the time, please show us your code which shows the time declaration and how you call the function. Showing the errors is good if you have any.

Comment: Thx :D I'll edit! ^^

Comment: Are you talking about validating data before it is saved (ie max expiration interval = 3 days from now), or about checking a value that was retrieved from the database (is the expiration date reached yet)?

Comment: Yep, check a value that was retrieved from the database! Its need to be valid for 3 day, else the users need to generate a new key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `isWithinNext(3)` you are testing if the `token_time_exp` is between now and 3 in the future, but when you save an user's `token_time_exp`, you set it to the current date, so it won't work.

You should use `wasWithinLast(3)` instead, or save the `token_time_exp` with a date 3 days in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Your `isWithinNext(3)` check might not make sense, imagine a 5 day interval exists in the database, it would start being valid 2 days after is has been set, and would then be valid for 3 more days. In case this is the behavior that you are aiming for, well then your check is just fine.

In case you want an expiration interval that is larger than 3 days to be valid too, ie you don't don't care whether the date expires in 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 days, then you'd instead use

```
$user->token_time_exp->isPast()
```

which evaluates to `true` when the expiration date is at least 1 second in the past (`< now`), or

```
!$user->token_time_exp->isFuture()
```

which evaluates to `true` when the expiration date equals the current date or is at least 1 second the past (`<= now`).

Comment: These functions, "isFuture" or "isPast", I did not find in the documentation.. Is it cake 2.x?

Comment: @ThiagoMoraes They are [**provided by Carbon**](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon#comparison), which \Cake\I18N\Time extends. I'm going to delete my answer later on, as I misunderstood your question.